# What's the right way to normalize a convolution filter?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

I'm following [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feConvolveMatrix) instructions. But my results aren't coming out right. I'm using this kernel:

```
-1 -1 -1
-1  8 -1
-1 -1 -1
```

So that means the sum for a given convolution will be between -8 and 8, assuming I have already normalized my input (0-255 -> 0-1). Then I do the convolution. Then I find the percent my value is between the minimum and maximum values. For example, with this kernel my min is -8 and max is 8. So if the value is 0 that's 50% which works out to 255 * .5 = 127.5. But that's clearly not right and what it gives is a mostly gray image. The parts that aren't gray are still monochrome even though I'm running the kernel on each channel individually.

[image]

```
    static int EvaluateKernelAtPoint(Bitmap bitmap, Matrix<double> kernel, int x, int y, Func<int, int, int> onGetIntensity)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < kernel.ColumnCount; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < kernel.RowCount; b++)
            {
                var xn = x + a - 1;
                var yn = y + b - 1;

                var intensity = (double)onGetIntensity(xn, yn); // returns R,G, or B color channel at that pixel
                intensity /= 255; // intensity is 0-1
                sum += intensity * kernel.At(a, b);
            }
        }

        var result = (sum - (-8d)) / (8d - (-8d)); // find the % between the min and max of -8 and 8
        result *= 255; // bring it back to 0-255
    }
```

Comment: Those extremes are extremely unlikely. You indeed want to set the zero to 127 or 128, then you can choose a scaling that will make your image look good. One approach is to find the min and max in the output image.

Comment: "The parts that aren't gray are still monochrome": don't expect the Laplacian output to show meaningful colors. Also, applying different gain coefficients to the three channels is not recommended as it introduces a bias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no right way to normalize, because the range is content-dependent.

In good RGB images, the range of values is usually [0, 255], provided the dynamic range is well adjusted.

But the output of this Laplacian filter, which can be seen as the difference between the original image and a smoothed version of it, usually has much smaller amplitude. But this depends on the local variations: an already smooth image will give no response, while noise (especially salt & pepper) can yield huge values.

You also need to decide what to do with negative values: shift so that zero appears as mid-gray, clamp to zero or take the absolute value.

Taking the min-max range and mapping it to 0-255 is an option, but leads to a "floating" zero and uncontrolled gain. I would prefer to set a constant gain for a set of images of the same origin.

Last but not least, histogram equalization is another option.

Comment: Allright, I will try fiddling with those values. It's on the back burner right now though. Quick question, the reason I got confused is because I was comparing my image to what you get in the browser with a -1 -1 -1 -1 8 -1 -1 -1 -1 convolution filter. Any guesses on what the browser might be doing here? https://jsfiddle.net/5zcro4hf/

Comment: Yeah, it looks good to me. I just can't figure out how to get my own code to do it. If I follow the steps on mozilla (which point to the w3c spec which I have only read a couple parts of) I don't get the same result. I think the code in my question is a faithful interpretation of their pseudo code (bias would be 0 and divisor would be 1 so I've left them out of this question). That's why I'm confused about the results not matching up.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: who are you addressing ?

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: you were asking "Did you ever get yours [your problem] resolved". I have no problem, and my answer explains what the options are. That is confusing.